# How to multiply an IndexedRowMatrix by another IndexedRowMatrix in spark mllib

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I am learning how to use spark mllib to calculate the product of two matrics.Now my code is like this:

```
val rdd1=sc.textFile("rdd1").map(line=>line.split("\t").map(_.toDouble)).zipWithIndex().map{case(v,i)=>(i,v)}.map(x=>IndexedRow(x._1,Vectors.dense(x._2)))
val rdd2=sc.textFile("rdd2").map(line=>line.split("\t").map(_.toDouble)).zipWithIndex().map{case(v,i)=>(i,v)}.map(x=>IndexedRow(x._1,Vectors.dense(x._2)))
val matrix1=new IndexedRowMatrix(test1)
val matrix2=new IndexedRowMatrix(test2)
```

I want matrix1 multiply matrix2 and I tried this:

```
matrix1.multiply(matrix2)
```

But matrix2 must be a local matrix，can't be IndexedRowMatrix(said in the API doc)

```
def multiply(B: Matrix): IndexedRowMatrix
Multiply this matrix by a local matrix on the right.
B:a local matrix whose number of rows must match the number of columns of this matrix
returns:an IndexedRowMatrix representing the product, which preserves partitioning
```

Is there others way to do this?

Comment: why are you creating an IndexedRowMatrix? for what purpose? why don't you create directly a Matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the local matrix and multiply before creating the second `IndexedRowMatrix`.

`val dArray = sc.textFile("rdd2").map(line=>line.split("\t").map(_.toDouble))` gives you the array of `Double` you need.

You can use `Matrices.dense(rows, columns, dArray)` and multiply with the first matrix.

Then you can continue creating the `IndexedRowMatrix` for the second matrix.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to multiply 2 IndexedRowMatrix using the RDDs, but you need to write it by yourself. Notice that in the implementation that I'm showing you get a DenseMatrix as result.

### Background

Let's assume you have 2 matrices *Amxn* and *Bnxp*, and you want to compute *Amxn * Bnxp = Cmxp* (typically n >> m and n >> p, otherwise you wouldn't be using IndexRowMatrices)

An *A(i)mx1* is the *i* **column vector** of *Amxn* and it's stored in a row of IndexedRowMatrix. Similarly, *B(i)1xp* is the *i* **row vector** stored in a row of the correspondent IndexedRowMatrix.

Also it's not difficult to prove that [image: C = sum(C_i)] such that 
[image: foo+bar]

These two operations described above can be easily implemented in a map+reduce operation, or more efficiently in a *.treeAggregate* when *nxp* is big.

### Version 1: Using Breeze

Simple implementation using Breeze Matrices to perform the multiplications, assuming your matrices are dense (if not you can do some further optimizations).

```scala
import breeze.linalg.{DenseMatrix => BDM}

def distributedMul(a: IndexedRowMatrix, b: IndexedRowMatrix, m: Int, p: Int): Matrix = {
  val aRows = a.rows.map((iV) => (iV.index, iV.vector))
  val bRows = b.rows.map((iV) => (iV.index, iV.vector))
  val joint = aRows.join(bRows)
  def vectorMul(e: (Long, (Vector, Vector))): BDM[Double] = {
    val v1 = BDM.create(rows, 1, e._2._1.toArray)
    val v2 = BDM.create[Double](1, cols, e._2._2.toArray)
    v1 * v2  // This is C(i) 
  }
  Matrices.dense(m, p, joint.map(vectorMul).reduce(_ + _).toArray)
}
```

**Notes**

- *numRows()*, *numCols()* on *IndexedRowMatrix* can be costly. If you know the dimensions you can provide them right away as arguments
- Instead of a *join* you can use a *cartesian*, however you need to add an *if* and return zero matrix when indexes are different

### Version 2: Using BLAS

This version is more efficient than the other (there is another version using only Scala arrays but it's extremely inefficient). You need to place it in an object because BLAS is not serializable.

```scala
import com.github.fommil.netlib.BLAS

object SuperMul extends Serializable{

   val blas = BLAS.getInstance()

   def distributedMul(a: IndexedRowMatrix, b: IndexedRowMatrix, m: Int, p: Int): Matrix = {
     val aRows = a.rows.map((iV) => (iV.index, iV.vector))
     val bRows = b.rows.map((iV) => (iV.index, iV.vector))
     val joint = aRows.join(bRows)
     val dim = m * p
     def summul(u: Array[Double], e: (Long, (Vector, Vector))): Array[Double] = {
       // u = a'(i)*b(i) + u
       blas.dgemm("N", "T", m, p, 1, 1.0, e._2._1.toArray, m, e._2._2.toArray, p, 1.0, u, m)
       u
     }
     def sum(u: Array[Double], v: Array[Double]): Array[Double] = {
       blas.daxpy(dim, 1.0, u, 1, v, 1)
       v
     }

Matrices.dense(m, p, joint.treeAggregate(Array.fill[Double](dim)(0))(summul, sum))
   }

}
```